# jquery add event for custom rows does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add click events only to the columns in a row that has some text in the first column. 
For the first row the click events should hide the rows that contain "1/" in the first column.
Here is my html table:

```
<table class="results">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Distribution_Approval_Archive_WorkFLow</td>
<td>0h:2m:59s:845ms</td>
<td><font color="red">TestFail</font></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1/1</td>
<td>MyLogin</td>
<td>0h:0m:8s:298ms</td>
<td><font color="green">TestCasePass</font></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1/2</td>
<td>OpenEFlowEnterprise</td>
<td>0h:0m:13s:912ms</td>
<td><font color="green">TestCasePass</font></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Distribution_Approval_Archive_WorkFLow</td>
<td>0h:2m:59s:845ms</td>
<td><font color="red">TestFail</font></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2/1</td>
<td>MyVismaLogin</td>
<td>0h:0m:6s:223ms</td>
<td><font color="green">TestCasePass</font></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2/2</td>
<td>OpenEFlowEnterprise</td>
<td>0h:0m:5s:158ms</td>
<td><font color="green">TestCasePass</font></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

And here is my jQuery for adding the events:

```
for (i=1; i <= $(".results td:nth-child(1):not(:contains('/'))").parent().length; i++){
    $($(".results td:nth-child(1):not(:contains('/'))").parent()[i-1]).children().click(function(){
        $('.results td:nth-child(1):contains("'+ i +'/")').parent().slideToggle("fast");
    })
}
```

Can you help fix the jQuery code?

Comment: I'm not sure `.parent()` will return more than 1 element.

Comment: parent() returns only one element for each of the elements from evaluating the selector; however , the loop was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never bind events in loops,try the following

```
$('tr').find('td:first-child()').not(':contains("/")').parent().click(function(e){
   var index = $(this).find('td:first-child()').text().split('/')[0];
   $('td:contains("'+index+'/")').parent().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help - is good to know that I can't  bind events in loops. I tried the code but click are also being added to all rows.

Comment: did you check my jsfiddle?

Comment: Based on your answer I managed to make it work: `$('tr td:nth-child(1):not(:contains("/"))').parent().click(function(){
   var index = $(this).find('td:first-child()').text().split('/')[0];
   $('td:contains("'+index+'/")').parent().slideToggle("fast");
});
`

Comment: you want to bind the event to the tr ,why didn't you say so :)

Comment: yeah, first time I tried to bind it to each column, but binding it to the row seems more reasonable :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can code:

```
$(".results td:nth-child(1):not(:contains('/'))").on("click", function(){
      var i = $(this).text().split('/')[0];
      $('.results td:nth-child(1):contains("'+ i +'/")').parent().slideToggle("fast");
     });
```

Comment: this is also good - clicking only the column without "/" to toggle the dispay

Answer (score 0):

Final code that I used for this (http://jsfiddle.net/danginkgo/jr5qvqj3/):

```
$('.results tr td:first-child:not(:contains("/"))').parent().click(function(){
  var i = $.trim($(this).find('td:first-child').text().split('/')[0]);
  $('.results td:first-child:contains("'+ i +'/")').parent().slideToggle("fast");
});
```